# Mosquitto broker authentification even for same machine clients

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am working on a MQTT project using local mosquitto broker.

Currently for testing, I want my broker to require authentication even from same machine clients. But it looks like the broker is allowing them even if they don't have the username or the password.

my mosquitto.conf:

```
allow_anonymous true
password_file C:\Documents\...\password_file.txt
```

Comment: Please remember to upvote Ben's answer if it was useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Mosquitto v2.0.x and newer just remove the `allow_anonymous true` or set it to `false` (for previous versions)

When set to `true` mosquitto will allow clients to connect without a username or password.

Comment: I have tried it. But no difference. Does the fact that my broker and client are running on the same machine have an effect?

Comment: Edit the question to show the output from when you start mosquitto, details of how you are starting mosquitto and details the client. As it is there is not enough information to debug this anymore.

Comment: I found the mistake. My bash command was "mosquitto.exe -v" instead of being "mosquitto.exe -v -c mosquitto.conf". Now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Writing this for others who may be in the same situation as I was.

> mosquitto.exe -v -c mosquitto.conf

solved the problem.